# Cleaner way of conditional Rendering in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have these multiple checks within JSX using ternirary operators while conditional rendering in react. One problem is that its compulsory to define the else block and i have an empty string in that case. Which bothers me tbh. Is there any better, CLEANER way of doing this?

```
{order.productClass ? (
                <li style={style.pLocation}>
                  <SettingsInputComponentIcon style={style.rightCardIcon} />
                Product Class :
                  <label
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: 5,
                      color: "gray",
                      fontSize: "16px",
                      fontWeight: "normal",
                    }}
                  >
                    {order.productClass}
                  </label>
                </li>
              ) : (
                  ""
                )}
```

I have multiple checks like this in my component and this doesnt look clean.

Another way is using && with the item.

```
{order.deliveryTime && (
                <li style={style.pLocation}>
                  <ScheduleIcon style={style.rightCardIcon} />
                Dispatch Time :
                  <label
                    style={{
                      color: "gray",
                      fontSize: "16px",
                      fontWeight: "normal",
                      marginLeft: 5,
                    }}
                  >
                    {order.deliveryTime}
                  </label>
                </li>
              )}
```

Is there a better, cleaner way than the aforementioned?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely make use of `&&`

`Ternary Operator` makes sense when you need to have a Loading state as well.

`If..Else` would make sense when there are a lot of moving pieces.

Also, try to make things modular. Will help you with organizing your components, makes things more readable and somewhat helps in debugging.

I hope that answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this which looks like a cleaner way.

```
<div style={{ display: order.deliveryTime ? '' : 'none' }}>

      <li style={style.pLocation}>
          <ScheduleIcon style={style.rightCardIcon} />
             Dispatch Time :
               <label
                 style={{
                      color: "gray",
                      fontSize: "16px",
                      fontWeight: "normal",
                      marginLeft: 5,
                    }}
                 >
                 {order.deliveryTime}
              </label>
      </li>

</div>
```

This is using css display property. If there is delivery time then display the content otherwise display nothing.